# How to wait for all async tasks to finish in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

My program needs to run many async tasks.

And one task must run when all async tasks complete.

How can I make this function to wait all async functions?

```
let urls=[....]

for(var i=0; i<urls.length; i++){
    doRequest(urls[i])
}
finish()



function doRequest(url){
    request({
      uri: url,
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        //do some tasks
    });
}

function finish(){
    console.log('finish')
}
```

Comment: [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: ^ works well in conjunction with [Bluebirds Promisifyall](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) for nodeback api's that don't return a promise.

Comment: pass in `i` to `doRequest`, along with `length` and compare on each callback.

Comment: You could checkout async.waterfall, though there a few to choose from based on what you may need: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2265406&seqNum=2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Promise are exactly what you need. They're native in JS nowadays, no need for extra libraries.

```
function finish () {
    console.log("finish");
}

function doRequest (uri) {
    // wrap code in promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(
            { uri },
            (error, response, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    // error case, similar to "throw"
                    reject(error);
                }
                else {
                    // success case, similar to "return"
                    resolve({ response, body });
                }
            }
        );
    });
}

let urls=[...];

// Basic way to do it:
Promise.all(urls.map(doRequest)).then(finish);

// async/await notation:
// you must be in an "async" environement to use "await"
async function wrapper () {
    await Promise.all(urls.map(doRequest));
    finish();
}
// async function return a promise transparently
wrapper();
```

Comment: You dont need the async await syntax if you just wrap `finish()` in a `.then()`, `Promise.all(urls.map(doRequest)).then(finish)`. Still like the answer so upvoted.

Comment: I wrote both solutions, you read too quickly and missed the line :) I introduced the async-await syntax because it can be handy in other cases.

Comment: I also like `await Promise.all(...)` for what it's worth.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution that doesn't require rewriting everything using promises, would be to check the number of completed requests at the end of `doRequest` function, and call `finish` if all requests have been completed.

```
let urls=[....]
let completed = 0

for(var i=0; i<urls.length; i++){
    doRequest(urls[i])
}

function doRequest(url){
    request({
        uri: url,
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        //do some tasks

        completed++
        if (completed === urls.length) {
            finish()
        }
    });
}

function finish(){
    console.log('finish')
}
```