# Looping in Asynchronous programming

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm pretty new to async. programming. I confuse how to do iteration.
I'm trying to iterate db queries. And right after the iteration is done I want to redirect user to the home page. Here's my code:

```
for(var i =0; i < venue_1_split.length; i++){
    pool.query("INSERT INTO peminjaman_venue VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
              [id_event, venue_1_split[i], id_google_calendar, 
              waktu_mulai_1, waktu_selesai_1, tanggal_peminjaman_1,  
              tanggal_peminjaman_1, hari_event_rutin],
             function(err, rows, fields){
                if(err) throw err;
    })
}



   //when the iteration is done.
   res.redirect('/');
```

How to achieve that? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait for all async tasks to finish in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127835/how-to-wait-for-all-async-tasks-to-finish-in-node-js)

Comment: I have used something like callback, promise and async/await in my code. But when it come to iteration i just cant find the solution @JJJ

Comment: ...I just linked the solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to map over your array instead of doing a for loop. Since this is asynchronous, you'll want to wrap your `.map` in a `Promise.all` and call `.then` to ensure that it awaits all the promises before continuing. Something like this should work for what you're trying to do:

```
Promise.all(venue_1_split.map(venue => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO peminjaman_venue VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
      [id_event, venue], id_google_calendar, 
      waktu_mulai_1, waktu_selesai_1, tanggal_peminjaman_1,  
      tanggal_peminjaman_1, hari_event_rutin],
      (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(err) rej(err)
        res()
    })
  }
}))
.then(r => res.redirect('/'))
.catch(err => {console.log(err); res.status(500).send()}) // or whatever you want to do with errors
```

Comment: Probably should show handling an error if the promise rejects.

Comment: Probably want something like `.catch(err => {console.log(err); res.sendStatus(500);})`

Comment: All data inserted to db BUT, there's an error "Cant set header after they are sent," That indicates res.redirect() called multiple times @AlexDovzhanyn

Comment: Try changing `res.status(500).send()` to `res.sendStatus(500)`

Comment: I edited your code. There were several mistakes.  In then() I added req.flash('message_success', 'Succeed'),
res.redirect('/')

Comment: Now the code works perfectly, the message shows up BUT the error still there in console log

Comment: Sure, I was just going off the code you provided, had no way of knowing what exactly you wanted to do beside insert into the database before redirecting

Comment: Are you doing anything after the .then is called, later in your code?